# Liferay - PreLoginAction - Prevent User from Login

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, liferay-hook

i use a Liferay based website and try to implement a login hook which prevents a user login under certain conditions. I want to make it as simple as possible like:

```
    @Override
    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ActionException
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            //redirect to login page, send a message back but just don't let the user login
            //but don't block or ban him either.
        }
    }
```

It has to look like a wrong password error, but it has to be on portal side, before the user even logins (therefore PreLoginAction class)

Edit: Okay, i used the logout and redirect method to go back to the login page. But i still want to generate a error message. I tried it like this

```
    @Override
    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ActionException
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            SessionErrors.add(request, "error");
            response.sendRedirect("/c/portal/logout");
        }
    }
```

and for the login.jsp i added the top line, but i guess its not working like that for the Login Actions. There is no error message showing

```
<liferay-ui:error key="error" message="this-account-has-been-locked" />
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= AuthException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= CompanyMaxUsersException.class %>" message="unable-to-login-because-the-maximum-number-of-users-has-been-reached" />
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= CookieNotSupportedException.class %>" message="authentication-failed-please-enable-browser-cookies" />
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= NoSuchUserException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= PasswordExpiredException.class %>" message="your-password-has-expired" />
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserEmailAddressException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserLockoutException.class %>" message="this-account-has-been-locked" />
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserPasswordException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserScreenNameException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />
```

Is there another way?
i also tried the line

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("loginError", "failure message");
```

and tried to read `${loginError}` in the jsp, but its also not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply redirect the user to `response.redirect("/c/portal/logout")` which will actually logout the user and redirect him to the home page.

If you want to programmatically logout the user yourself and then redirect, you can use the following code :

```
    @Override
public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ActionException {

    if (condition) {

        // Whatever here ...

        // Logout the user.
        request.getSession().invalidate();

        // Redirect
        response.redirect(<YOUR_PAGE>)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this solution and the redirection worked. i had to use response.redirect("/c/portal/logout") because the invalidate() method simply didn't work for me for some reasons. I still have one concern. I want to add a message after redirecting. i also edited my question to explain my problem more detailed

Comment: the logout do an `session.invalidate();` so anything you put in the session is not more present

Comment: May be your Liferay user is not yet authenticated; this is why `session.invalidate();` didn't work.

Comment: So is there a way to create a message with this solution? if the logout process runs`session.invalidate()` as well, can i use something else to inform the user why this login attempt didn't work?

Comment: The easy way is to create a public Liferay jsp page, let's consider it's called `error.jsp`. You can redirect to this jsp with a parameter like this  `response.redirect("error.jsp?errorId=0")` and get the error id and print the corresponding error message.

Comment: Thanks. Can i send this paramter to my front page with the login window? Like `response.redirect("/web/start?errorId=0")`. Because, if i redirect it like this, my login.jsp can't read the parameter errorId. It is always null, although you can see it in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the authetication pipeline you can make an authenticator that check the conditions

```
public class CustomAuth implements Authenticator {
    @Override
    public int authenticateByEmailAddress(long companyId, String emailAddress, String password, Map<String, String[]> headerMap, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) throws AuthException {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int authenticateByScreenName(long companyId, String screenName, String password, Map<String, String[]> headerMap, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) throws AuthException {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int authenticateByUserId(long companyId, long userId, String password, Map<String, String[]> headerMap, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) throws AuthException {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

an add your authenticator to the pipeline in portal.properties

```
auth.pipeline.pre=package.CustomAuth
```

or

```
auth.pipeline.post=package.CustomAuth
```

Or you can use a Authentication Verifier

```
public class CustomVerifier implements AuthVerifier{
    @Override
    public String getAuthType() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthVerifierResult verify(AccessControlContext accessControlContext, Properties properties) throws AuthException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and configure it to the pipeline in portal.properties

```
auth.verifier.pipeline=
```

In your case maybe the best choice is the **AuthVerifier**